# Is there a "Rails Way" include a jQuery plugin in the Asset Pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

Many jQuery plugins have the following directory structures:

```
/<plugin name>
../css
../images
../js
```

The CSS files usually have relative links to the images in them. What I want to do is include these plugins in the `Rails Way` under the Asset Pipeline, and hopefully that doesn't involve having to renamed the file references to remove the relative links. Is there such a Rails Way?

Could it also be that it's overkill to include an already-minified jQuery plugin in the Asset Pipeline?

Comment: What about using ``//= require_tree ./[plugin_name]`` to require the all directory with plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to add your assets to the load path  which is the recommended way, as far as I know. If the application you're running has the assets-pipeline activated, it should find your assets after expanding the path in your application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("plugins/plugin_name/assets/")
```

Not shure, if this is what you asked for but if not, you should check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

*Remeber to restart your server*

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and also tried to find "the Rails way" to do this. And this is what I ended up with at the end of the day:

As Rob already mentioned:

> **vendor/assets** is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks.

Source: [2.1 Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

Lets take a practical example: using the [`jquery_datepicker`](https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker) gem (Note: we had to use a workaround because of this issue: [*bundle pack does not work with git sources*](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/67)).

1) Installing the gem (pretty straighforward):

```
cd vendor/gems
git clone https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker.git
```

2) Add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery_datepicker', :path => 'vendor/gems/jquery_datepicker'
```

3) Install a jquery-ui theme

- From [*ThemeRoller*](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) select a theme, check Datepicker and Slider
  and the jQUery version
- Download and extract the content of the package
- CSS/images from the `css/theme-name` folder move them:

  - `jquery-ui-1.8.xx.custom.css` to `app/vendor/stylesheets/`
  - the `images` folder to `app/vendor/images/` (yes, move the entire folder `images` so you end up with something like this `app/vendor/images/images/ui-icons_256x240.png`
- i18n from the `development-bundle/ui/i18n` folder (optional) move them to:

  - Create a folder `i18n` under `app/vendor/javascripts/`
  - move `jquery.ui.datepicker-xx.js` to this folder `app/vendor/javascripts/i18n/`
  - make sure the `i18n` folder is loaded so include in `application.js`

```
//= require_directory ./i18n
```

`vendor/assets` is loaded automatically AFAIK so you don't have to include the path in the asset pipeline.

I'd like to see how others are approaching this, it's a very good question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you haven't received an answer is because it's kind of unclear what you're asking. Are you asking if it's overkill to put your plugins in the asset pipeline? Are you asking if you have to rename file references?

I always put all my jquery plugins in my asset pipeline. Overkill or not, there all in one place and they only get compiled once so even if compiling them takes longer, it doesn't affect my app.

Comment: These plugins usually have their own directory structure though. Do you preserve that, or do you move the CSS to the /stylesheets directory, the images to the /images directory, etc?

Comment: That's the part I'm confused about. Because if I preserve the directory structure of the plugin, in which subdirectory of /assets pipeline do I place it?

Comment: Personally i move the css to the /stylesheets directory and the images to the /images directory and then i change the paths as needed. You can pretty much go into the css file and do a find on "url" and then you'll catch all the image paths.